# Regression of paired data in R with covariates

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, multiple-regression

I have a dataset with multiple response variables (clinical measurements such as BP, HEIGHT, WEIGHT) and samples are paired because same measurements are taken before and  after treatment. And duration of treatment divides the sample into 3 groups (3 months, 2 months and 1 month).
I want to extract meaningful information about the effect of treatment (before and after) and whether duration of treatment matters in terms of these response variables.
how do I construct my mixed model and what type of hidden effects I should look for?

my initial thought was

```
lmer(measurement1 ~ before1.after2 + (1|subjects), data = data)
```

this formula for each group of treatment done separately, but I am not sure of this approach? How do I look into the effect of duration of treatment (i.e., Group variable) as well?

dataframe I am working with:

```
> str(data)
'data.frame':   90 obs. of  56 variables:
 $ subjects                       : Factor w/ 45 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
 $ before1.after2                 : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Group                          : Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ measurement1                   : int  26 27 21 22 21 22 20 19 19 25 ...
 $ measurement2                   : chr  "6.26" "15.42" "16.56" "8.62" ...
 $ measurement3                   : chr  "5.2" "4.8" "5.5" "4.8" ...
```